# Bootstrap SASS grid-float-breakpoint

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass

I have the following in my main.scss file where I've defined Bootstrap 3.2.2's variables in an attempt to change the point the mobile menu shows. Everything I've read to date simply shows changing the grid-float-breakpoint but it simply does not change.

I am not interested in manually adjusting the CSS to match the behavior, so adjusting this variable is my only preference.

```
$screen-md-min: 960px !default;

$grid-float-breakpoint: $screen-md-min;
$grid-float-breakpoint-max: ($grid-float-breakpoint - 1) !default;

// bower:scss
@import "../../bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss";
// endbower
```

It's important to note: every other aspect of Bootstrap and my implementations operate perfectly fine. Every other update to the main.scss file is reflected in the browser via Browsersync + Gulp.

The result is the same default behavior whereby the navigation shows at 767px and below.

Because I'm using Roots'.io Sage on a WordPress setup, there's no way to provide a demo.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

It turns out everything above was okay.

The problem involved a Bootstrap hover fix Bower dependency which included Bootstrap as a dependency which, ultimately, conflicted with the Bower bootstrap-sass-official dependency.

Cheers!